# Ubuntu FingerPrint error

Tags: asus

I tried Ubuntu 22.04 and my fingerprint works, but there's a bug. In Windows, I can just tap my finger to unlock, but in Ubuntu, I have to swipe and sometimes the sensor doesn't read my fingerprint correctly and shows "invalid fingerprint." I also tried Ubuntu 23.04. My laptop is Asus with an ELAN fingerprint sensor.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Can you please edit your question to include the model of your Asus laptop (to help others in the future with this issue). Also, please run the command `lsusb` and include that in your question, as this will provide the hardware ID of the fingerprint reader, which will help in resolving your issue. Thanks

Comment: the problem already solved
with reinstalling fingerprint gui\n
thanks you

Comment: great to hear. Please mark your question as resolved so others can benefit from your experience and resolution. Thanks

Comment: please give some detail about the solution, I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found this trick and my fingerprint

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

My system run Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic with kernel 6.5.0-10-generic

W O R K S ! ! ! ! ! !

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm1ig_VFxSs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1326088)